# Open app while specific phone number calls

Tags: android

I want to open or maximize app working in background while specific phone number calls. Is that possible? 
Where can I find more info?

Comment: I think it is possible

Answer (score 0):

Use a broadcast receiver for reading the Phone state when you receive a call.Then if the phone number which you have received is specific then start an activity